# Converting Multiple Frequency/Count Columns to Percentages

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe like this, listing out the counts by Day.

```
**Color**     **Monday** **Tuesday** **Wednesday**
Green            2            3           1
Orange           3            5           5
Blue             1            3           2
Red              4            5           1
```

What I want to get to is something like this. Where the columns are percents.

```
**Color**     **Monday** **Tuesday** **Wednesday**
  Green            20%        20%       10%
  Orange           30%        30%       60%
  Blue             10%        20%       20%
  Red              40%        30%       10%
```

Any ideas on how to do this without manually converting once column at a time?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `mutate_if()` in combination with a custom function, such as:

```
percent_mean <- function(x){
        m <- round(x/sum(x),2)*100
        return(paste0(m, sep = "%"))
}

library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate_if(is.numeric, funs(percent_mean))
#   Color Monday Tuesday Wednesday
#1  Green    20%     19%       11%
#2 Orange    30%     31%       56%
#3   Blue    10%     19%       22%
#4    Red    40%     31%       11%
```

Comment: I think this works for the formatting, but it doesn't actually calculate the percentages does it?

Comment: you mean column percentages? please clarify

Comment: yes. Sorry. My example is flawed now that I look at it. I want to calculate the percentage that each color represents on Monday, Tuesday, Wed, etc. Each column should sum to 100%.

Comment: This works brilliantly. You have made my day! Thanks!